# Why does Javascript spread maintain defined keys that are set to undefined, and how do they differ from non-existent keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined, spread-syntax

I have a code sample below that demonstrates this. I ran into this unexpected behavior of the spread operator where a key that gets set as `undefined` is not treated the same way keys that have never been defined are. Both have the `typeof` that is `undefined` but they are not entirely the same.

I'm trying to understand how/why this is. I've been operating under the mistaken assumption that setting a key's value to `undefined` is the equivalent of removing the key (e.g. they're both lost if you JSON.stringify their values). Now, I'm trying to understand how they differ and what effects that has on other use cases

Note: I thought this was a Typescript thing but tested again in JS with the same issue.

```js
const obj1 = {a: "apple", c:"crab", d:"dagger", e: undefined};
const obj2 = {a: "aardvark", b:"blue", c: undefined, f: "flamethrower", g: undefined};

const res1 = {
  ...obj1,
  ...obj2
};

const res2 = {
  ...obj2,
  ...obj1
};

const res3 = {
  ...obj1
};

console.log(res1);
console.log('====');
console.log(res2);
console.log('====');
console.log(res3);
console.log('====');
console.log(typeof res3.e);
console.log(typeof res3.h);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

Comment: It includes all [enumerable own properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#traversing_object_properties) - `"e" in obj1`, although its _value_ is indeed `undefined`, but `"h"` isn't.

Comment: You've still defined the key and given it the value of `undefined`, so therefore it exists for the Spread operator to include. `I've been operating under the mistaken assumption that setting a key's value to undefined is the equivalent of removing the key` This is clearly the source of your confusion as it's not the case.

Comment: To be clear, `typeof res3.e` returns `undefined` because *that's the value you gave it*. `typeof res3.h` returns `undefined` because it doesn't exist and the interpreter is being very tolerant of mistakes and instead of throwing an exception when trying to access a property which does not exist, it simply returns `undefined` and lets execution continue.

Comment: The `in` operator can be used to check if a string is a property name of an object. That works regardless of the property value, so `"e" in res3` would be `true`, while `"h" in res3` would be false.

Comment: Read about [`undefined` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)